# How send big string in winsock using c++ from client to server

Tags: c++, winsock

I am writing a server-client application using Winsock in c++  for sending a file line by line and I have a problem in sending huge string. The line size is very huge.

For getting the message from the client by the server I use the code below.

```
int result;
char message[200];

while (true)
{
    recv(newSd, (char*)&message, sizeof(message), 0);

    cout << "The Message from client: " << message << ";";
}
```

The above code working fine if I send small length of the message. But, what I wanted is to send an unknown size of lines in a file.

How to send a big unknown **string** instead of **char message[200];**

Comment: Have you considered using something like `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<std::byte>` instead of your fixed size C-style array?

Comment: do you get  the result in pieces?

Comment: @JesperJuhl 

but I see that **recv** function definition is below where i have to pass a type of char *.

WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int PASCAL recv (SOCKET, char *, int, int);


Not sure, how to pass char * type when I declare message as a **string** or **vector**

Comment: @swamybabun [std::vector::data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), [std::string::c_str()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Comment: *How to send a big unknown string instead of char message[200];* -- Another issue is that you wouldn't use `recv` in that way you're showing us.  You need to loop on `recv` until it is `<=0`, concatenating onto an existing string.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a byte stream, it knows nothing about messages or lines or anything like that.  When you send data over TCP, all it knows about is raw bytes, not what the bytes represent.  It is your responsibility to implement a messaging protocol on top of TCP to delimit the data in some meaningful way so the receiver can know when the data is complete.  There are two ways to do that:

- send the data length before sending the actual data.  The receiver reads the length first, then reads however many bytes the length says.
- send a unique terminator after sending the data. Make sure the terminator never appears in the data.  The receiver can then read until the terminator is received.

You are not handling either of those in your `recv()` code, so I suspect you are not handling either of them in your `send()` code, too (which you did not show).

Since you are sending a text file, you can either:

- send the file size, such as in a `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` (depending on how large the file is), then send the raw file bytes.
- send each text line individually as-is, terminated by a `CRLF` or `bare-LF` line break after each line, and then send a final terminator after the last line.

You are also ignoring the return value of `recv()`, which tells you how many bytes were actually received.  It can, and usually does, return fewer bytes than requested, so you must be prepared to call `recv()` multiple times, usually in a loop, to receive data completely.  Same with `send()`.